# XAMPP MySQL and phpmyadmin stop working after first use

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I install XAMPP MySQL only works on the first use. once I close the program and reopen it I get this error if I try to start MySQL:

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums

EDIT: and this is listed in the mysql error log, I don't exactly understand it:

2013-10-28 21:10:41 2428 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace lorecloud/userbasicinfo uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\lorecloud\userbasicinfo.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/innodb_index_stats which uses space ID: 2 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.

And if I try to access phpmyadmin I get this:

## 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Apache still starts and runs just fine. I have uninstalled and reinstalled everything, and I have the same problem every time after the first use. what is wrong?

Comment: Have you pressed the "Logs" button to look at the error logs?

Comment: @MikeBrant now I did....edited the question to include it.

Comment: Have you tried the recommended recovery steps mentioned in the error log?

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm totally new to xampp I have no idea how to know if there is a permissions problem, much less change it.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem by looking in the Apachefriends forums. It appears this issue is not uncommon, so if anyone comes across this issue, the problem is that the latest version of xampp doesn't shut down MySQL correctly if you just hit stop or close it. You have to click "shell" on your xampp control panel and type:

```
mysqladmin shutdown --user=root --password
```

And it will prompt you to enter the password, then shut down properly. You must do this each time you close the program if you've had MySQL running.